# how do i paste code into haml without it complaining?

Tags: haml

I have the following code, and hate having to indent code to the same line when I just want it to stay as it is?

What I have to indent it to:

```
.content.first
Thank you for taking our Survey, hope you had fun!!!
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="mc_embed_signup" style="text-align:center">
<form onsubmit="_kmq.push(['record', 'sign up for our newsletter'])" action="http://socialcrunch.us5.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=755f44e55d468b9568a7ec9de&amp;id=7f27e118c4" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
%label{:style=>"text-align:center"}
  %br
  Like spandex wearing gym freaks, SocialCrunch is in training.
  %br
  %br
  You have been one of the first people to take part in a test which will form the basis of our website.
  %br
  %br
  Input your email below to learn more about SocialCrunch and our launch later this summer!
  %br
  %br
  Thank you for taking part, we hope you had fun.
<input style="margin-left: 21%;text-align:center" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
<div class="clear"><input style="margin-left:33%" type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Can I run it through some filter that will ignore my indentation and wont complain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAML syntax is indentation sensitive  and there is no 'filter' which will ignore your indentation. HAML uses indentation to convert your code properly to respective HTML code blocks.

If you are tired of manually indenting your haml code and are using emacs as your editor then you can follow the instructions here

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/HamlMode

and permanently solve your problem